# How can I pivot a table so that the rows become columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this named `people`:

| first_name | id | total | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | 1234 | 13 | onsite |
| Joe | 1234 | 9 | remote |
| Jane | 4321 | 99 | remote |
| Jane | 4321 | 1 | onsite |

I want to query it and have the results returned like this:

| first_name | id | onsite | remote |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | 1234 | 13 | 9 |
| Jane | 4321 | 1 | 99 |

I believe I need to use Pivot() but this is advanced for me

Thank you

I tried grouping by first_name but that doesn't move the rows to columns

Comment: You could also use `conditional aggregation`.

Comment: [`crosstab()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html#TABLEFUNC-FUNCTIONS-CROSSTAB-TEXT) or [aggregate `filter`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [aggregate `filter`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) clause. [Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/Rbu2NP7-)

```
select first_name,
       id, 
       sum(total)filter(where type='onsite') as onsite,
       sum(total)filter(where type='remote') as remote
from test
group by first_name,
         id;
```

| first_name | id | onsite | remote |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | 1234 | 13 | 9 |
| Jane | 4321 | 1 | 99 |

Or look into [`crosstab()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html#TABLEFUNC-FUNCTIONS-CROSSTAB-TEXT):

```sql
create extension tablefunc;

select * from crosstab(
   $a$ select first_name, id, type, total from people order by 1,2,3 $a$ , 
   $b$ select distinct type from people order by 1 $b$
  ) AS ct(first_name text, id int, onsite int, remote int);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the `conditional aggregation` method, which is easy to comprehend and IMO recommended if you have just a couple different "types".

```
select 
 first_name, 
 id, 
 max(case when type = 'onsite' then total end) as onsite, 
 max(case when type = 'remote' then total end) as remote
from people
group by first_name, id
```

Comment: No need for the case statement, use FILTER(). Besides that, you need SUM instead of MAX

Comment: @FrankHeikens Based on OP's sample data, MAX() is fine. If there are multiple rows per type, then I agree, SUM() is needed.